# Como pegar valor de um formulario para outro?

Tags: delphi

Tenho o formulário 1 e nele tem um campo que na ação onExit eu pesquiso o código no banco e se não achar eu apresento uma mensagem se deseja cadastrar um produto. Se sim abre o formulário 2, agora eu não estou conseguindo pegar o campo gerado e enviar para o formulário 1, segue o modelo:

```
with form do
 begin
   form:=Tfrm_formulario2.Create(Application);
   Centraliza_Form(form);
   form.ShowModal;
   if(form.ShowModal=mrYes)then
      begin
         campo.campos^[2].valorInteiro:= form.campoCodigo.AsInteger; 
      end;
   Release; 
end
```

No formulario 2 na ação do botão salvar quero que a tela se feche e retorne o valor do campoCodigo, segue o código:

```
ModalResult := mrYes;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua abordagem é estranha, não consegui identificar algumas propriedades lendo seu Código!

Minha abordagem seria usar variáveis globais, pois, você deseja fechar o Formulário 2 e voltar ao Formulário 1 passando os dados, logo os dados do Formulário 2 estão inacessíveis.

Declare uma variável Publica no seu Formulário 1, quando clicar em Salvar faço algo do tipo:

```
procedure Formulario2.btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Formulario1.NomeVariavelPublica := NovoCodigo;
  Close;
end;
```

No Formulário 1 você passa o valor da variável: `NomeCampo.text := NovoCodigo`

Lembrando que a propriedade Text deve receber String, se foi cadastrado na variável Inteiro deve converter: `IntToStr(NovoCodigo)`.

Comment: Vlw Junior, criando a variavel global funfou certinho aki :D